Problems syncing my style.css chrome workspace changes with my local file
I've had problems with this for years, but more so now.
I am working on a project using Python's simple web server.
Using chrome dev tools, I added my folder to the WorkSpace
The changes I make through dev tools are sometimes, synced, but they frequently lose syncing, and I am not sure why. I have tried the following.

Hard reload with clean cache
Cleaning browser history
Closing all project windows and reopening them
Deleting and readding project

Nothing works!

I wonder if the fact that I have multiple subfolders with the same file name might be creating conflicts.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
